# How do I correctly turn this string into an Integer?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to be able to the value inside the list and verify if its an integer inside a string then turn it into an integer and delete anything that isn't a integer and return the list.

I already tried isinstance() and I couldn't get it to work and I also tried converting them into difference types and it didn't work.

```
def turnListToInt(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if lst[i].isdigit():
            int(lst[i])
        else:
            del lst[i]


def askQuestion():
    ask = input("How may I help you?")
    if ask == "":
        print("Thats Not A Valid Question")
    elif ask == "Multiply" or "multiply" or "*":
        ask = input("What Numbers?")
        numbers = ask.split();
        numbers = turnListToInt(numbers)
        print(float(numbers[0])*float(numbers[1]))
while run:
    askQuestion();
```

I expect list = ["2","and","5"] to turn into list = [2,5].

Comment: +1 for putting some effort into your question and clearly stating what result you expected (but didn't achieve).

Comment: If you found any answer useful and solved your problem, consider accepting one by clicking the tick button next to the corresponding answer.

Answer (score 1):

This should to the trick:

```
def turn_list_to_int(lst):
    return [int(v) for v in lst if v.isdigit()]


test = ["2", "and", "5"]
print(turn_list_to_int(test))
```

Output

```
[2, 5]
```

This code basically constructs a new list (using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)) with only values that are digits and converts them into ints (ignoring all the others).

Your solutions have multiple problems, viz:

1. Your `i` is an item from `lst` and not an index. That's because you are iterating over the list when you use the notation `for i in lst`. If you wanted indices there, the correct way is to do it like this: `for i in range(len(lst))`.
2. You mutate `lst` in `turnListToInt` but you don't return back the list.
3. `int(lst[i])` is useless, (assuming that `i` is an index of `lst`, which is not in your code) you are converting an element of `lst` into int but you don't actually store that value anywhere, for example: `lst[i] = int(lst[i])` will make more sense.
4. When you iterate over a list using a for loop and indices since your initial intent was to mutate the list, when you delete items from the list at the same time then your for loop at some point will try to access an element not anymore available in the list because your list will shrink due to the deletion of elements and an index will be out of bounds of the shrunk list.

Answer (score 0):

Your `turnListToInt` is almost correct. As written it does not return anything, so you should be sure to return something.

Also, when you do `for i in lst`, i is each item in the list. If you want an index, a handy Python function is [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate), which returns an index and the item.

However in this case, we do not need the index. I propose constructing an entirely new list and only appending to it when we have a digit:

```
def turnListToInt(lst):
    newlist = []
    for item in enumerate(lst):
        if item.isdigit():
            newlist.append(int(item))

    return newlist


def askQuestion():
    ask = input("How may I help you? ")
    if ask == "":
        print("Thats Not A Valid Question")
    elif ask == "Multiply" or "multiply" or "*":
        ask = input("What Numbers? ")
        numbers = ask.split();
        numbers = turnListToInt(numbers)
        print(float(numbers[0])*float(numbers[1]))
while True:
    askQuestion();
```

Another piece of advice is to try to run code in the interactive console (command line). That way you can see the results right away. Also, you can add lots of `print` statements when debugging your code. You can `print` just about any variable or object and you'll get some more information.

### Update

@Rafael rightly points out that editing `lst` directly while iterating through it is not a good idea. By coincidence, a previous version of my code worked on "2 and 5" input. Instead, I created a new list and appended to it. An alternative solution would be to enumerate over a reversed version of list, so deleted indexes don't get mixed up.